# Sending Selected Variant SKU via Whatsapp Button

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am trying to send the selected variant SKU via my custom built whatsapp button but it's sending only pre-selected SKU via whatsapp. I want your help to suggest me a proper code snippet to solve this problem.

[image: product template]

file name *product-template.liquid*

The code for variable sku i am using.

`{% assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}`
`<span>SKU-</span><span class="variant-sku">{{ current_variant.sku }}</span>`

The whatsapp button code.

`<a href="https://wa.me/91XXXXXXXXXX?text={{ current_variant.sku }}" class="shopify-payment-button__button shopify-payment-button__button--unbranded" style="border-radius:0px; background-color:#25d366">Buy on Whatsapp</a>`

The Problem with this code.

When i open a product page and click on buy on whatsapp button it sends pre-selected SKU but when i select any other variant it send that previews pre-selected SKU not the current one i have selected. The current_variant.sku data doesn't change accordingly but shows on product page below product.title correctly.

Also i want some condition on my whatsapp button.

1. if the product.type is = "X" then whatsapp button should be visble otherwise not.
2. if the current selected variable is not available in inventory the whatsapp button should be hide just like Shopify's built-in regular add to cart or buy now button does.

- All these conditions should be in real time i.e. doesn't requires the page reload/refresh.

I am using Debut Theme.

Thanks
I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, I think you have a typo.here `product.selected_or_first_available_variant` it should be `product.selected or first_available_variant`. I might be wrong :)

Comment: @YashMaheshwari thank you for your comment but it's not typo. please see below page for ref. https://shopify.dev/tutorials/customize-theme-show-sku-numbers

Comment: Hi Try this one: https://www.shopify.in/partners/blog/product-variants. Use the code snippet from this blog.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari this is not helpful in my case.